# RHEL 8 manage server boot order

Tags: linux, redhat

We run RHEL 8 servers we need to ensure NFS share is available or service running before start another service that depend on NFS share because that service need R/W into/from NFS share.
what our options to achieve this request ? can we control which service will run on which order?
I understand there is an option to add 'Required' entry into service.
please assist.

BR
Shlco

Answer (score 1):

A systemd shortcut for depending on a certain path be mounted is [RequiresMountsFor](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=). Convenient as only the path is required, it will figure out the mounts needed.

Making up an example, say service `thing` requires NFS share `/srv/data` to be mounted. Taking advantage of drop-in directories, this override can be applied separately from the rest of the unit:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/thing.service.d/mount.conf
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/srv/data
```

Comment: thank you, by adding RequiresMountsFor= entry is service will be "wait" to NFS share to be available or service start process will failed ? the requirement that service will wait until NFS share will be available and then start the service.